# How to dispatch data to redux from the common api request file?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I have created a common js file to call the service requests. I want to store the fetched data in my redux managed store. But I am getting this error saying `Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.`I think this is because I am not using react-native boilerplate for this file. But the problem is I don't want to I just want to make service requests and responses.

```
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { addToken } from "../redux/actions/actions";

const { default: Axios } = require("axios");
    const dispatch = useDispatch();   

const handleResponse=(response, jsonResponse)=> {
   // const dispatch = useDispatch(); //-----also tried using dispatch here
    const jsonRes = jsonResponse;
    const { status } = response;
    const { errors } = Object.assign({}, jsonRes);
    const resp = {
        status,
        body: jsonResponse,
        errors,
        headers: response.headers,
    };
    console.log(resp, 'handle response');

    return await dispatch(addToken(resp.body.token))
};

const API = {
    makePostRequest(token) {
  Axios({
            url: URL,
            ...req,
            timeout: 30000
        }).then(res => 
                console.log('going to handle');
                await handleResponse(res, res.data)
            })
    }
export default API
```

I know there would be some easy way around but I don't know it

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `useDispatch` from `react-redux`, but `dispatch` from `redux`.
You need to use `redux-thunk` in your application.

Look at the example in this article [Redux Thunk Explained with Examples](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/redux-thunk-explained-with-examples/)

The article has also an example of how to use redux with asynchronous calls (`axios` requests in your case).

I suggest to refactored your api to differentiate two things:

1. fetcher - it will call your api, e.g. by `axios` and return data in Promise.
2. redux action creator (thunk, see the example in the article) - it will (optionally) dispatch `REQUEST_STARTED` then will call your fetcher and finally will dispatch (`REQUEST_SUCCESS`/`REQUEST_FAILURE`) actions.

The latter redux action creator you will call in your react component, where you will dispatch it (e.g. with use of `useDispatch`)